# Heavy automatition with scripting for videos - ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

Been here i found a lot of question involving ffmpeg and its filters, however the filters are already built-in and what you generally do is calling them with various parameters.

What was wondering is if ffmpeg or other FLOSS software supports some more advanced scripting for do things like automatic cut and join pieces with transitions based on certain audio highlights or other heavy automatition things less hard-coded and more coding aimed.

A sort of script support for ffmpeg would be the ideal because all the things could be carried inside the powerful ffmpeg core without have to use an intermediate lossless codec in order to not lose video quality with extra transcoding.

PS: this question can have many answer because out of there probably exists many softwares.. tease me with lot of things please :D I would like stuff that can manipulate a lot the audio video and metadata streams but coded possibly.

Comment: I think you have to distinguish between tasks that are supposed to happen in preparing videos and others that can or should happen during playout, depending on your usage scenario. Liquidsoap can do some of the things you are looking for, but not all of them and is aimed towards realtime usage... http://liquidsoap.fm/download.html

Comment: Generally I would say that all you want to do could be done with a combination of OpenCV, Ffmpeg and liquidsoap.

Comment: Need to be more specific about what automation you want.